# FAISS Embeddings cannot be saved because of langchain import error

Tags: pdf, langchain, huggingface, large-language-model, faiss

I am following this [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RIWbalZ7sTo&ab_channel=PromptEngineering)

I am using a sample pdf from [here](https://www.africau.edu/images/default/sample.pdf)

But I replaced OpenAI with Huggingface for the embeddings

Below is my code:

```
import os
import pickle
from pprint import pprint
from PyPDF2 import PdfReader
from langchain.vectorstores import FAISS
from langchain.embeddings import HuggingFaceEmbeddings
from langchain.text_splitter import RecursiveCharacterTextSplitter

pdf = 'sample.pdf'
pdf_reader = PdfReader(pdf)
text = ''
for page in pdf_reader.pages:
    text += page.extract_text()
pprint(text)

text_splitter = RecursiveCharacterTextSplitter(
    chunk_size = 100,
    chunk_overlap = 20,
    length_function = len
)
chunks = text_splitter.split_text(text = text)

embeddings = HuggingFaceEmbeddings()
VectorStore = FAISS.from_texts(chunks, embedding = embeddings)
with open('sample.pkl', 'wb') as f:
    pickle.dump(VectorStore, f)
```

When i check the sample.pkl file, all i see is this line: `No module named 'langchain'`

I also checked the embeddings without saving it to the file, and i can see them

Im using jupyter notebook, with python 3.9.16, and I have all the libraries installed. And YES I do have langchain installed. I wouldnt be able to import FAISS or HuggingFaceEmbeddings or RecursiveCharacterTextSplitter without it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I tried it in another computer with the same environment, and had the same error.

Turns out I was running the jupyter notebook and python script in `python 3.9.16`, but the `.pkl` file that was being saved was using the default computer version of `python 3.11.1`.

So all I had to do was install all the required libraries on my default `3.11.1` version, and everything worked perfectly

Answer (score 0):

I can see you didn't enter any repo_id, model_kwargs, huggingfacehub_api_token parameters inside HuggingFaceHub(). Make sure you installed -> pip install langchain

Comment: all of these are env variables, already set
And ofcourse i have langchain installed, I wouldnt be able to do the previous steps if they werent